# Как узнать последнюю цифру у числа(int) в JAVA?

Tags: java

Мне нужно узнать последнюю цифру у числа (`int`) в *JAVA*.

Например у нас есть число (`int`):

```
int count = 12345;
int lastСharacter;
```

Мне нужно, чтобы `lastCharacter` содержал в себе последнюю цифру `count`.
То есть 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Последняя цифра числа равна остатку от деления на 10, lastCharacter = count%10